# How to convert array of key–value objects to array of objects with a single property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects like this:

```js
[
  { "key": "fruit", "value": "apple" },
  { "key": "color", "value": "red" },
  { "key": "location", "value": "garden" }
]
```

I need to convert it to the following format:

```js
[
  { "fruit": "apple" },
  { "color": "red" },
  { "location": "garden" }
]
```

How can this be done using JavaScript?

Comment: If you’re looking for a variant where the result is a single object with all properties merged: [How do I convert array of Objects into one Object in JavaScript?](/q/19874555/4642212).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var data = [
  {"key":"fruit","value":"apple"},
  {"key":"color","value":"red"},
  {"key":"location","value":"garden"}
];

var result = data.map(function (e) {
  var element = {};
  element[e.key] = e.value;
  
  return element;
});

console.log(result);
```

also if you use `ES2015` you can do it like this

```
var result = data.map((e) => {
   return {[e.key]: e.value};
});
```

[`Example`](http://www.es6fiddle.net/ijckgyn8/)

Answer (score 6):

Using an arrow function, with the data called `arr`

```
arr.map(e => {
    var o = {};
    o[e.key] = e.value;
    return o;
});
```

This generates a new *Array* and does not modify the original

It can be simplified down to one line as

```
arr.map(e => ({[e.key]: e.value}));
```

---

If you can't assume arrow function support yet, you would write this longhand

```
arr.map(function (e) {
    var o = {};
    o[e.key] = e.value;
    return o;
});
```

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Nope, arrow functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Arrow functions are ES6, so make sure that your platform supports ES6.

Comment: @AlexK. according to MDN it should in Safari and IE9 and greater. I haven't tested personally though. If you have to support <IE9, may God have mercy on your soul ;)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan As of today (2016-01-12), [**all versions of IE below 11 have reached end of life**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support)

Answer (score 1):

Using map (as suggested in other answers) or the following will do what you want...

```
var data = [{"key":"fruit","value":"apple"},{"key":"color","value":"red"},{"key":"location","value":"garden"}];
var obj = {};

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  obj[data[i]["key"]] = data[i]["value"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, obj.property and obj['property'] return same things.
obj['property'] is more flexible because the key 'property' could be a string with some space :

```
obj['pro per ty'] // work
obj.pro per ty // not work
```

or

```
var a = 'property';
obj.a == obj.property // => false
obj[a] == obj.property // => true
```

---

**So you could try that.**

```
var data = [{"key":"fruit","value":"apple"},{"key":"color","value":"red"},{"key":"location","value":"garden"}]
var new_data = [];

var data_length = data.length; // just a little optimisation for-loop
for (var i = 0; i < data_length; i++) {
    var item = data[i]; // to have a vision close of foreach-loop (foreach item of collection)
    new_data[i] = {};
    new_data[i][item.key] = item.value;
}
console.log(new_data);
// [{"fruit":"apple"},{"color":"red"},{"location":"garden"}]
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer that will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What you currently have is an array of object, each having two attributes, key and value. If you are not aware of map, you can always run a forEach loop on this array and rearrange the data. Try something like below:

```
  function() {
     var newArray = [];
     oldArray.forEach(function(x){
     var obj= {};
     obj[x.key] = x.value;
     newArray.push(obj);
    });
  console.log(newArray);
}
```

here oldArray is your original data